# React good practice for response of a modal

Tags: reactjs

I want some advice about good practice to "wait" (litteraly or not) for a response of the user.

If my id is 2 I must open the modal to let the user choose a side (right or left). The only way I found to not modify the component before his response is to keep the information needed (image and stats) in a "waitingX" state.

Once the modal is closed and I have the answer, I can give my state the good id (modified by the modal) and get other param from my states.

```
handleChildClick(src, id, stats) {
    if(id === 2) {
        this.setState({modaling: true, waitingImage: src, waitingStats: stats});
    }else{
        this.setState({clickedItem: src, clickedId: id, clickedStats: stats});
    }
}


handleModalResult(choice){
    this.setState({modaling: false, clickedId: choice, 
clickedStats: this.state.waitingStats, clickedItem: this.state.waitingImage});
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that this is not a good way to go but don't have any ideas about how I should handle it.

How can I achieve this in a proper way?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your components need _some_ kind of state to indicate to itself that it needs to draw that modal at all, so what makes you think your `waiting` is not appropriate? I'd personally call it "showModal", but the role is the same: making sure the component renders the modal during (any and all) `render()` calls until either the modal's called my onResult handler, or my onCancel handler.

Comment: I thought that it was not appropriated because if the modal is closed (user wants to finally cancel and close it) information would be stored in waitingImage and waitingStats but never used. These information would be eventually replaced later (if the user pops the modal again)

Comment: Yes, so: make sure to clear those values when you handle either the modal's result, or the signal that the modal got cancelled. Keeping track of "what you'll need later" is fine, and throw that away after you're doing with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll clear them for sure then